# Monogame: Could not load asset as a non-content file

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm just getting started with MonoGame, and whenever I run my program I get a Could not load asset as a non-content file error. I've been searching the web and haven't found anything on my problem. please help!

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace MoveDemo
{

public class MainGame : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture2D mainmenu;

    public MainGame()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }


    protected override void Initialize()
    {

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        mainmenu = Content.Load<Texture2D>("MainMenu"); 
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }


    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();


        base.Update(gameTime);
    }


    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(mainmenu, new Rectangle(0, 0, 840, 480), Color.White );
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you've added the file through the content pipeline tool and that it builds?

Answer (score 2):

You certainly *can* do it like @SBurris says, but I will suggest a simpler and overall better solution to the problem:

**The cause:**

So when you try to debug your project in Visual Studio, you get a `ContentLoadException` which tells you that an asset can not be loaded as a non-content file. What is a `content file`, you ask? A `content file` is a binary file containing the compiled asset and has an `.xnb` extension. When specifying the path to your asset (e.g. a texture) like this:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    this.Content.Load<Texture2D>("path/to/myTexture");
}
```

You aren't actually linking to the `.png` file of your texture, rather you link to the `.xnb` content file which holds the data you require. The exception simply tells you that no content file (`.xnb`) was found in the specified directory.

**The solution:**

So to fix this, simply open the `MonoGame Content Builder/Pipeline tool`, which resides in a folder called `Content` in your project's directory. The pipeline tool itself is also called `Content` (or Content.mgcb) and has MonoGame's orange logo as it's icon.

Once you've done that, add the asset you need to your `Content Project` (by default called `Content`) by right clicking on it `-> Add -> Existing Item`.

And then you save and done! Wrong. In order to have the content file compiled and ready for use, you need to `create` it first. That's done by clicking on the `Build menu` and selecting `Build` or alternatively, press F6 on your keyboard.

This will compile the `asset file` into a `content file` for you and your game will be ready to read it.

**XNA:**

When I first started with MonoGame, I had experience with Microsoft's XNA and when I found out that MonoGame utilizes a different approach to adding assets to a project, I had the same problem like you. That is because I was used to the XNA way which allowed me to simply `Add -> Existing item` and forget about it -- Visual Studio would compile the asset files automatically for me. Well, that is no longer the case with MonoGame so remember to build your `Content Project` from the `Content Pipeline tool`!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Did you tell Visual Studio the MainMenu was content and to copy it?

[image]

In my case, since the CarBlue is in a `Graphics` folder under content I load it with this line:

```
blueCarSprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Graphics\CarBlue");
```